# Python linear regression diagnostic plots similar to R

Tags: python, plot, regression, linear-regression

I'm trying to get diagnostic plots for a linear regression in Python and I was wondering if there's a quick way to do this.

In R, you can use the code snippet below which'll give you a residuals vs. fitted plot, normal Q-Q plot, scale-location, residuals vs leverage plot.

```
m1 <- lm(cost~ distance, data = df1)
summary(m1)
plot(m1)
```

**Is there a quick way to do this in python?**

There's a great blog post that describes how you can use Python code to get the same plots as R would give you but it requires quite a bit of code (compared to the R approach at least). Link: https://underthecurve.github.io/jekyll/update/2016/07/01/one-regression-six-ways.html#Python

Comment: You can create a function / module and then import it and use a one-liner like `my_plot(formula, data)`. This is what R does under the hood as well. Some R code that might (not sure, sorry) be the source of `plot`: https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/plot.lm.R

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to storing everything in `pandas` and plot with `DataFrame.plot()` whenever possible:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
import scipy.stats as stats
import statsmodels.api as sm


def linear_regression(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    """Perform a univariate regression and store results in a new data frame.

    Args:
        df (DataFrame): orginal data set with x and y.

    Returns:
        DataFrame: another dataframe with raw data and results.
    """
    mod = sm.OLS(endog=df['y'], exog=df['x']).fit()
    influence = mod.get_influence()

    res = df.copy()
    res['resid'] = mod.resid
    res['fittedvalues'] = mod.fittedvalues
    res['resid_std'] = mod.resid_pearson
    res['leverage'] = influence.hat_matrix_diag
    return res


def plot_diagnosis(df: DataFrame):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
    plt.style.use('seaborn')

    # Residual against fitted values.
    df.plot.scatter(
        x='fittedvalues', y='resid', ax=axes[0, 0]
    )
    axes[0, 0].axhline(y=0, color='grey', linestyle='dashed')
    axes[0, 0].set_xlabel('Fitted Values')
    axes[0, 0].set_ylabel('Residuals')
    axes[0, 0].set_title('Residuals vs Fitted')

    # qqplot
    sm.qqplot(
        df['resid'], dist=stats.t, fit=True, line='45',
        ax=axes[0, 1], c='#4C72B0'
    )
    axes[0, 1].set_title('Normal Q-Q')

    # The scale-location plot.
    df.plot.scatter(
        x='fittedvalues', y='resid_std', ax=axes[1, 0]
    )
    axes[1, 0].axhline(y=0, color='grey', linestyle='dashed')
    axes[1, 0].set_xlabel('Fitted values')
    axes[1, 0].set_ylabel('Sqrt(|standardized residuals|)')
    axes[1, 0].set_title('Scale-Location')

    # Standardized residuals vs. leverage
    df.plot.scatter(
        x='leverage', y='resid_std', ax=axes[1, 1]
    )
    axes[1, 1].axhline(y=0, color='grey', linestyle='dashed')
    axes[1, 1].set_xlabel('Leverage')
    axes[1, 1].set_ylabel('Sqrt(|standardized residuals|)')
    axes[1, 1].set_title('Residuals vs Leverage')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

There are still many features missing, but it provides a good start. I learnt how to extract influence statistics here, [Access standardized residuals, cook's values, hatvalues (leverage) etc. easily in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55764402/10181743)

[image]

By the way, there is a package, [dynobo/lmdiag](https://github.com/dynobo/lmdiag), having all the features.